# Can't open shipping methods in backend

Tags: magento-1, configuration, fatal-error

I just installed *Aheadworks Blog* for my Magento 1.9.2.4. Everything works, but now I can't open shipping methods in backend. I'm getting a blank screen and this message in the address:

```
index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/carriers/key/cabeaad86a668ce72a0f090233956f70/
```

I looked in the **system.log** and found this:

> Warning: 
>       include(/var/www/unoshop.dk/public_html/includes/src/smartsend_logistics_block_adminhtml_shipping.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/unoshop.dk/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

Don't know what that means. I tried reinstall the smartsend extension but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

clear your cache and session from the var folder delete cache/ and session/
if the problem percist share your log file

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is enabled compilation (point 3 of the extension installation guideline - 3. Disable compilation). Try to put “#” before each line starting from “define” in the file includes/config.php. Then rename the Magento cache folder into “var/cache”.